# Which version of install4j supports Apple Notarization Process

Tags: macos, install4j

I am using install4j 7.0.4 version. We are planning to use Apple Notarization Process. So, want to understand when and which install4j version will support Apple Notarization Process

Answer (score 0):

As of 7.x, notarization is not supported. Notarization is planned for 8.x which is currently under development.